# Какой падеж использовать - родительный или винительный

Tags: грамотная-речь, падежи, родительный-или-винительный

Какой падеж нужен здесь (родительный или винительный): "На данный момент... не предоставила описания (выполненной оценки)" или "... не предоставила описание..."?

Answer (score 1):

Обратимся к ставшему почти родным Д.Э. Розенталю:

> Родительный падеж, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение подчеркнутого отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях: 
>   [...] 6)      в устойчивых сочетаниях, пословицах, поговорках, чаще при выражении дополнения отвлеченным существительным, например: не испытывает желания, не питает надежды, не находит поддержки, не делает секрета, не дает ходу, души не чает, не принимает участия, не обращает внимания, не дает покоя, не имеет представления, не внушает доверия, не упускает возможности; Вчерашнего дня не воротишь; Чужой тайны не поверяй. Также при конкретном значении существительного: не спускает глаз, не покладая рук; Денег куры не клюют; Лежа хлеба не добудешь; Плетью обуха не перешибешь; Своего локтя не укусишь; Шила в мешке не утаишь.

"Не предоставила описания" не относится к устойчивым выражениям, ввиду чего здесь предпочтителен все же винительный падеж: "не предоставила описание".

Answer (score 0):

Как и в предыдущем примере, здесь лучше использовать В. п., так как дополнение выражено существительным с конкретным значением.